# Joining with the most recently-entered value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table that shows work tickets, basically like this:

```
TABLE "ticket"
ticket_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ticket_name VARCHAR(64)
```

Then I have a table showing the possible list of status codes for a ticket:

```
TABLE "status_ticket"
status_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
status_name VARCHAR(64)
```

And I have one more table that logs the history of the statuses that a ticket has or has had:

```
TABLE "xref_ticket_status"
xref_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ticket_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
status_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

When the ticket is created, an entry is made in the `ticket` table for the ticket, and then an entry is made in the `xref_ticket_status` table assigning a status to the ticket by linking the `ticket` table to the `status_ticket` table.  When the status changes, a new entry is made in the `xref_ticket_status` table to reflect the new status.  This way, I have a history of each status that a ticket has had and when it was assigned.  The most recent entry for any given `ticket_id` in the `xref_ticket_status` table is the ticket's current status.

I'm not sure how I would join these three tables together to get a ticket's current status.  Essentially, I want to join the `ticket` table with the `xref_ticket_status` table where `ticket_id` matches but for the newest `created` column in the `xref_ticket_status`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select ti.ticket_id,ti.ticket_name,
xr.created, st.status_name
from ticket ti
inner join xref_ticket_status xr
on(ti.ticket_id = xr.ticket_id)
inner join status_ticket st
on(xr.status_id = st.status_id)
group by ti.ticket
order by xr.xref_id desc;
```

===============Update==================

```
select * from
(select ti.ticket_id,ti.ticket_name,
xr.created, st.status_name
from ticket ti
inner join xref_ticket_status xr
on(ti.ticket_id = xr.ticket_id)
inner join status_ticket st
on(xr.status_id = st.status_id)
group by ti.ticket
order by xr.xref_id desc)cs
order by cs.ticket_name desc; //or asc
```

Comment: Does this solution limit me to ordering by `xr.xref_id desc`? For instance, if I wanted the returned results to be ordered by `ti.ticket_name` instead, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following gets the most recent `status_id` and `ticket_id` from `xref_ticket_status`:

```
select xts.*
from xref_ticket_status xts
where not exists (select 1
                  from xref_ticket_status xts2
                  where xts2.ticket_id = xts.ticket_id and
                        xts2.created > xts.created
                 );
```

The logic is:  "Get me all rows from `xref_ticket_status` where there is no row with the same ticket id and a more recent created date".  The would be the last date for each ticket.  And note that you can also use `xref_id` for the comparison rather than the date.

The rest is just joining the tables together and choosing your desired columns:

```
select t.*, ts.*, xts.created
from xref_ticket_status xts join
     ticket t
     on xts.ticket_id = t.ticket_id join
     ticket_status ts
     on xts.status_id = ts.status_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from xref_ticket_status xts2
                  where xts2.ticket_id = xts.ticket_id and
                        xts2.created > xts.created
                 );
```

Comment: Should there be an `and` or `or` somewhere in the subquery's where clause?

Comment: @NickCoons . . . Yes, an `and` in fact.